# Getting error on selecting those columns also which are not used to create group while using using group by?

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by

I am using PostgreSQL

If I want to get customer.first_name, customer.last_name or any other column in addition to customer_id and sum(total), I am getting error as shown below:

```
select i.customer_id, cu.first_name, cu.last_name, sum(total) as amount from invoice i
join customer cu
on i.customer_id = cu.customer_id
group by i.customer_id
order by amount desc
```

```
ERROR:  column "i.customer_id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
LINE 1: select i.customer_id, cu.first_name, cu.last_name, sum(total...
               ^ 
SQL state: 42803
Character: 8
```

So, I was just experimenting and found that when I wrote the query in the following query, it's working fine:

```
select cu.customer_id, cu.first_name, cu.last_name, sum(total) as amount from invoice i
join customer cu
on i.customer_id = cu.customer_id
group by cu.customer_id
order by amount desc
```

Why is it so?
Even when there is only one table and I select other columns also which are not used to create group by, I get the same error.
Then how can I select other columns also while using group by?

Comment: *Why is it so?* , not enough info provided to give a proper answer but, guessing would be that  `customer_id` might be primary key on `customer` table

Comment: Both query shouldn't work.  It doesn't make sense to not group the non-aggregated columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Why is it so? Even when there is only one table and I select other
> columns also which are not used to create group by, I get the same
> error. Then how can I select other columns also while using group by?

The second query works because all the columns in `customer` table are functionally dependent on `customer_id(PK)` (even if you haven't posted your table description).

In simple words , every record is unique in `customer_id` column and it doesn't matter how many columns you add from the `customer` table because every row would be returned.

Second query would fail if `customer_id` isn't declared as primary key,

See [this example](https://dbfiddle.uk/Tt_1tyaj) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to select additional columns (cu.first_name, cu.last_name) along with the aggregated column (sum(total)) without including them in the GROUP BY clause or using an aggregate function on them. In standard SQL, when you use GROUP BY, you can only include columns in the SELECT clause that are either part of the GROUP BY clause or are being used in aggregate functions like SUM, COUNT, AVG, etc. This is because when you group data, the database needs to know how to aggregate the non-grouped columns.

cu.customer_id is an identifier and is enough, for postgres sql to know how to group data

in mysql there is a function that allow you to write your query without group by by disabling ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY, but in postgresql there is not such behavior

Comment: This answer doesn't explain why second query is running fine despite not grouping nor aggregating by some fields.

Comment: Because cu.customer_id is an identifier and you dont need to add all columns from that table

Comment: OK, you added that bit, now it's better :)

Comment: f that's the case, then why the second query is running? Here also, additional columns (cu.first_name, cu.last_name) are not in the GROUP BY clause or using an aggregate function on them. And, I know that cu.customer_id is an identifier so I dont need to add all columns from that table. I am adding the columns first_name and last_name because I need to get the names of the customer with the highest amount.